# Import MS Excel table to MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Excel database (my company CRM) which I am trying to import to MS Access (Northwind DB) database.
I am able to fetch the Excel file to my Access database (at the bottom of the Access). But my problem is I am not able to fetch the Excel tables directly into my Access database so that I do not have to enter them manually and it shows directly in my Customer List.
I hope I am clear. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean automatic insert of excel sheets? Like each change in Excel should synchronize immediately into Access database?

Comment: You're a little vague. What exactly happens/doesn't happen when you import? What are you looking to accomplish but it's not happening?

Comment: @DangeMast and Invent - Animate - Thank you for replying. I'm sorry for being bit unclear. Well, I am using MS Access Northwind template to build my company's CRM. Now I have an Excel file which has all my customers name, id, address, company, etc. If you see Northwind template there is a navigation to 'View Customers'. Here you can add new customers with all details but one by one. How do I import the Excel sheet to my Access database so that it automatically comes into my 'View Customers' tab? and I do not need to manually put the customers details.

Comment: i'm still not quite clear on what you are trying to achieve but it sounds like  you want to import Excel data into Access. see the instructions on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141228

Comment: Thank you pony2deer, DangeMask and Invent-Animate. Thanks for the help.